# Python os.path.join on Windows

Tags: python, windows, path-manipulation

I am trying to learn python and am making a program that will output a script.  I want to use os.path.join, but am pretty confused.  According to the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) if I say:

```
os.path.join('c:', 'sourcedir')
```

I get `"C:sourcedir"`.  According to the docs, this is normal, right?

But when I use the copytree command, Python will output it the desired way, for example:

```
import shutil
src = os.path.join('c:', 'src')
dst = os.path.join('c:', 'dst')
shutil.copytree(src, dst)
```

Here is the error code I get:

```
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:src/*.*'
```

If I wrap the `os.path.join` with `os.path.normpath` I get the same error.

If this `os.path.join` can't be used this way, then I am confused as to its purpose.

According to the pages suggested by Stack Overflow, slashes should not be used in join—that is correct, I assume?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Windows has a concept of current directory for each drive.  Because of that, `"c:sourcedir"` means "sourcedir" inside the current C: directory, and you'll need to specify an absolute directory.

Any of these should work and give the same result, but I don't have a Windows VM fired up at the moment to double check:

```
"c:/sourcedir"
os.path.join("/", "c:", "sourcedir")
os.path.join("c:/", "sourcedir")
```

Comment: os.path.join('C:/', 'sourcedir') worked as expected.

I thank you very much good sir :)

the others 
'//' 'c:'
'c:\\'
did not work (C:\\ created two backslashes, C:\ didn't work at all)

Thanks again ghostdog74, Smashery, and Roger Pate.  I am in your debt :)

Comment: Sorry, line breaks weren't kept in comment, it looks very messy

Comment: Even if this works in some cases, the answer by @AndreasT is a much better solution. Using os.sep will choose between / and \ depending on OS.

Comment: Is there any point in using `os.path.join` or `os.sep` if you're going to specify `c:` anyway? `c:` makes no sense on other OSs.

Comment: all these solutions are only partially satisfying. It is ok to manually add the separator when you have a single specific case, but in case you want to do it programmatically, what is the criteria for which `os.path.join('c:','folder')` works differently from `os.path.join('folder','file')`? Is it because of the `:` or because 'c:` is a drive?

Comment: the rule is probably 'don't add sep if single letter follow by colon'. I have implemented this rule in an answer below.

Answer (score 155):

To be even more pedantic, the most python doc consistent answer would be:

```
mypath = os.path.join('c:', os.sep, 'sourcedir')
```

Since you also need os.sep for the posix root path:

```
mypath = os.path.join(os.sep, 'usr', 'lib')
```

Comment: Excuse my ignorance - It looks like the code still varies between Windows and Linux, so what makes `os.sep` superior?

Comment: Please note this snafu when trying to inject `os.sep`.  It only works after the bare drive letter.



    >>> os.path.join("C:\goodbye", os.sep, "temp")


    'C:\\temp'

Comment: @pianoJames my answer builds off of this one to provide a system-agnostic solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51276165/3996580

Comment: I don't understand the point of all these "pedantic" solutions. `os.sep` is useful when you want to manipulate paths without making assumptions about the separator. It's pointless to use with `os.path.join()` since it already knows the right separator. It's also pointless if you end up needing to explicitly specify the root directory by name (as you can see in your own example). Why do `"c:" + os.sep` instead of simply `"c:\\"`, or `os.sep + "usr"` instead of simply `"/usr"`? Also note that in Win shells you can't `cd c:` but you can `cd c:\ `, suggesting that the root name is actually `c:\ `.

Comment: Point taken about the use of "\" and "/" for practical purposes. 

But, I don't know what point was trying to be made about "can't CD C:". 

In a Windows CMD shell "CD C:" shows the present CD value of the C: drive. You can certainly do this. 

The command "CD /D C:" will change the current directory to the present CD value of the C: drive. This is useful when you're on drive F: and want to move to drive C:.  But it is easier to just type 'C:' instead of 'CD /D C:'.

Answer (score 19):

For a system-agnostic solution that works on both Windows and Linux, no matter what the input path, one could use

```
def joinpath(rootdir, targetdir):
    return os.path.join(os.sep, rootdir + os.sep, targetdir)
```

On Windows:

```
>>> joinpath("C:", "Windows")
'C:\\Windows'
>>> joinpath("C:\\", "Windows")
'C:\\Windows'
>>> joinpath("C:\\Windows", "src")
'C:\\Windows\\src'
```

On Linux:

```
>>> joinpath("usr", "lib")
'/usr/lib'
>>> joinpath("/usr", "lib")
'/usr/lib'
>>> joinpath("/usr/lib", "src")
'/usr/lib/src'
```

Comment: Thanks! This is even more useful since it doesn't suffer from the gotcha that @Jobu mentioned earlier: os.path.join(os.sep, "C:\\a" + os.sep, "b") returns "C:\\a\\b" on Windows.

Comment: How are either of these examples system agnostic though? `c:` doesn't exist on *nix, and `usr` doesn't exist on windows..

Comment: The function call `os.path.join(os.sep, rootdir + os.sep, targetdir)` is system agnostic _precisely because_ it works with both of those system-specific examples, without needing to change the code.

Comment: This solution, much like the earlier post that inspired it, still relies on setting rootdir like `rootdir = "usr" if nix else "c:"`. But the more direct and accurate `rootdir = "/usr" if nix else "c:\\"` works just as well, without the `os.sep` acrobatics and ensuing head scratching. There's no danger that a root directory on *nix will start with anything other than a forward slash, or that Windows will have root directories named without a trailing colon and backslash (e.g. in Win shells, you can't just do `cd c:`, you'd need to specify the trailing backslash), so why pretend otherwise?

Answer (score 18):

To be pedantic, it's probably not good to hardcode either / or \ as the path separator.  Maybe this would be best?

```
mypath = os.path.join('c:%s' % os.sep, 'sourcedir')
```

or

```
mypath = os.path.join('c:' + os.sep, 'sourcedir')
```

Answer (score 15):

The reason `os.path.join('C:', 'src')` is not working as you expect is because of something in the documentation that you linked to:

> Note that on Windows, since there is a
>   current directory for each drive,
>   os.path.join("c:", "foo") represents a
>   path relative to the current directory
>   on drive C: (c:foo), not c:\foo.

As ghostdog said, you probably want `mypath=os.path.join('c:\\', 'sourcedir')`

Answer (score 7):

I'd say this is a (windows)python bug.

Why bug?

I think this statement should be `True`

```
os.path.join(*os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)).split(os.path.sep))==os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

But it is `False` on windows machines.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree that that constitutes a Python bug. Is this still the case? (_Written from the glorious utopian future of late 2015._)

Comment: I cannot answer this question with respect to windows, since I do not have access to a windows machine, but I guess python's behavior regarding this question hasn't changed.

Anyway, this statement is also not true for Linux implementations, since the first statement returns the path without the leading separator (a.k.a the root directory), whereas the second statement returns the path including the leading separator.

Comment: So I actually do not like my answer regarding this question anymore. But I also don't like python's behavior regarding this.

Comment: @Cecil I am on this question right now because of the same issue... it does appear to still be the case.

Answer (score 6):

to join a windows path, try

```
mypath=os.path.join('c:\\', 'sourcedir')
```

basically, you will need to escape the slash

Answer (score 4):

You have a few possible approaches to treat path on Windows, from the most hardcoded ones (as using raw string literals or escaping backslashes) to the least ones. Here follows a few examples that will work as expected. Use what better fits your needs.

```
In[1]: from os.path import join, isdir

In[2]: from os import sep

In[3]: isdir(join("c:", "\\", "Users"))
Out[3]: True

In[4]: isdir(join("c:", "/", "Users"))
Out[4]: True

In[5]: isdir(join("c:", sep, "Users"))
Out[5]: True
```

Answer (score 1):

Consent with @georg-

I would say then why we need lame `os.path.join`- better to use `str.join` or `unicode.join` e.g.

```
sys.path.append('{0}'.join(os.path.dirname(__file__).split(os.path.sep)[0:-1]).format(os.path.sep))
```

Comment: yeah, right, it's waaaaayy clearer that way. Why not using regexes while you're at it? or call a perl script and process the output?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea because os.path.join is pretty good semantics... So you see it in a code and understand straight away what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

answering to your comment : *"the others '//'  'c:', 'c:\\' did not work (C:\\ created two backslashes, C:\ didn't work at all)"*

On windows using 
**`os.path.join('c:', 'sourcedir')`**
will automatically add two backslashes **`\\`** in front of ***sourcedir***.

To resolve the path, as python works on windows also with forward slashes -> **'/'**, simply add **`.replace('\\','/')`** with **`os.path.join`** as below:-

**`os.path.join('c:\\', 'sourcedir').replace('\\','/')`**

e.g: **`os.path.join('c:\\', 'temp').replace('\\','/')`**

output : ***'C:/temp'***

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solutions are interesting and offer a good reference, however they are only partially satisfying. It is ok to manually add the separator when you have a single specific case or you know the format of the input string, but there can be cases where you want to do it programmatically on generic inputs.

With a bit of experimenting, I believe the criteria is that the path delimiter is not added if the first segment is a drive letter, meaning a single letter followed by a colon, no matter if it corresponds to a real unit.

For example:

```
import os
testval = ['c:','c:\\','d:','j:','jr:','data:']

for t in testval:
    print ('test value: ',t,', join to "folder"',os.path.join(t,'folder'))
```

> ```
> test value:  c: , join to "folder" c:folder
> test value:  c:\ , join to "folder" c:\folder
> test value:  d: , join to "folder" d:folder
> test value:  j: , join to "folder" j:folder
> test value:  jr: , join to "folder" jr:\folder
> test value:  data: , join to "folder" data:\folder
> ```

A convenient way to test for the criteria and apply a path correction can be to use `os.path.splitdrive` comparing the first returned element to the test value, like `t+os.path.sep if os.path.splitdrive(t)[0]==t else t`.

Test:

```
for t in testval:
    corrected = t+os.path.sep if os.path.splitdrive(t)[0]==t else t
    print ('original: %s\tcorrected: %s'%(t,corrected),' join corrected->',os.path.join(corrected,'folder'))
```

> ```
> original: c:    corrected: c:\  join corrected-> c:\folder
> original: c:\   corrected: c:\  join corrected-> c:\folder
> original: d:    corrected: d:\  join corrected-> d:\folder
> original: j:    corrected: j:\  join corrected-> j:\folder
> original: jr:   corrected: jr:  join corrected-> jr:\folder
> original: data: corrected: data:  join corrected-> data:\folder
> ```

it can be probably be improved to be more robust for trailing spaces, and I have tested it only on windows, but I hope it gives an idea.
See also [Os.path : can you explain this behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182253/os-path-can-you-explain-this-behavior) for interesting details on systems other then windows.

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by using:

```
os.sep.join(list('C:', 'sourcedir'))
```

`join` here is not from `os.path.join()`, but from `''.join()`

It can be useful in the following situation:

```
import os

some_path = r'C:\some_folder\some_file.txt'
path_items = some_path.split(os.sep)
same_path = os.sep.join(path_items)
```

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity's sake, a workaround:

```
my_path = r'D:\test\test2\file.txt' # original path string
drive_letter = my_path.split(':')[0] # avoid os.path.join relative path bs
my_path_parts = os.path.normpath(my_path.split(':')[1]).split(os.sep)

# do some path cmponent modifications here if you want

if drive_letter: # if drive letter exists
    drive_letter += ':\\'

my_new_path = drive_letter + os.path.join(*my_path_parts)
my_new_path
```

Answer (score 0):

In windows using `os.paht.join("/", "Temp")` will result in /Temp by default but as strange as it sounds, there is no problem in using that path as a full path equivalent to "C:/Temp" and it works for both saving files and opening files.