# Convert .xls to .xlsx so that Openpyxl can work with it

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlrd

I wrote a flask application that will be used to process some excel files, however, I wrote it for .xlsx files. The inputted files might be .xls files, which I know Openpyxl can't open. How can I convert the file to .xlsx before processing it with Openpyxl in my application?

I saw something online about using xlrd to write the original .xls to a .xlsx file that Openpyxl can process but I was having trouble tailoring it to fit my specific application.

Thanks in advance!

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Style, Font
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect, url_for, send_file
import os


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return """<center><body bgcolor="#FACC2E">
          <h1><p>Automated TDX Report</h1></p><br>
    <form action="/upload" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <p><input type=file name=file>
         <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form></center></body>"""

@app.route('/upload', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['file']
        f.save(f.filename)
        return process(f.filename)

def process(filename):


    VP = ['ZYJD', 'ZYJC', 'ZYKC', 'ZYKA', 'ZYKB', 'ZYKD', 'ZYKE', 'ZYKF', 'ZYJB', 'ZYJX', 'ZYKG', 'ZYKH', 'ZYJE', 'ZYJA', 
         'ZYKI', 'ZYKX', 'ZYKK', 'ZYKJ', 'ZYJF', 'ZYJK', 'ZYJG', 'ZYJJ', 'ZYKL', 'ZYKM', 'ZYKN']

    VA = ['ZYIC', 'ZYIB', 'ZYHC', 'ZYIA', 'ZYHA', 'ZYHG', 'ZYHB', 'ZYID', 'ZYDA', 'ZYIE', 'ZYHD', 'ZYIG', 'ZYIX', 'ZYHE', 
         'ZYIF', 'ZYHX', 'ZYDE', 'ZYHF', 'ZYLB', 'ZYAC', 'ZYCF', 'ZYDF', 'ZYBG', 'ZYDG', 'ZYDD', 'ZYDH', 'ZYCB', 'ZYCA', 
         'ZYWA', 'ZYWB', 'ZYWC', 'ZYWD', 'ZYWE', 'ZYWF', 'ZYWG', 'ZYWI', 'ZYWJ']

    Gordon = ['ZYDB', 'ZYDX', 'ZYEB', 'ZYED', 'ZYEC', 'ZYEA', 'ZYEX', 'ZYFE', 'ZYFX', 'ZYFD', 'ZYFA', 'ZYFC', 'ZYFB', 
             'ZYGC', 'ZYGA', 'ZYGX', 'ZYGB', 'ZYGF', 'ZYGG', 'ZYGD', 'ZYLA', 'ZYBF', 'ZYBE', 'ZYLD', 'ZYKM', 'ZYKN', 
             'ZYCC', 'ZYCE']

    Pete = ['ZYAD', 'ZYBX', 'ZYAX', 'ZYAB', 'ZYBC', 'ZYBA', 'ZYBB', 'ZYAA', 'ZYBD', 'ZYLE', 'ZYCX', 'ZYAE', 'ZYCC', 'ZYCE', 
           'ZYLA', 'ZYBF', 'ZYBE', 'ZYLD']

    Mike = ['ZYKP', 'ZYAP', 'ZYHP', 'ZYJP', 'ZYFP', 'ZYJR', 'ZYCP', 'ZYIR', 'ZYAR', 'ZYBP', 'ZYKR', 'ZYJS', 'ZYIP', 'ZYHR',
           'ZYEP', 'ZYFF', 'ZYGP', 'ZYKS', 'ZYEE', 'ZYJH', 'ZYII', 'ZYHH', 'ZYJW']

    workbook = load_workbook(filename)
    worksheet = workbook.active

    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('B', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('D', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('E', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('F', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('G', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('H', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('I', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('K', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('L', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('M', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('N', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('O', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('P', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('Q', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('R', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('S', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('T', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('U', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('V', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('W', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('X', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('Y', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('Z', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('AA', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('AB', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('AC', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('AD', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('AE', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('AF', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('AG', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('AH', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('AI', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('AJ', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('AK', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('AM', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('AN', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('AP', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('AQ', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('AR', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('AS', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('AT', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('AU', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('AV', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('AW', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('AX', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('AY', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('AZ', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('BA', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('BB', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('BC', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('BD', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('BE', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('BF', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('BH', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('BI', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('BJ', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('BK', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('BL', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('BM', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('BN', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('BO', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('BP', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('BQ', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('BR', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('BS', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('BT', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('BU', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('BV', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('BW', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('BX', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('BY', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('BZ', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('CA', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('CB', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('CC', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('CD', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('CE', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('CF', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('CG', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('CH', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('CI', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('CJ', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('CK', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('CL', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('CM', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('CN', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('CO', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('CP', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('CQ', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('CR', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('CS', hidden=True)
    worksheet.column_dimensions.group('CU', hidden=True)


    routecolumn = worksheet.columns[58]
    i = 2
    supervisorheader = worksheet.cell("CV1")
    s = Style(font=Font(bold=True))
    supervisorheader.style = s

    worksheet['CV1'] = 'Supervisor'
    for route in routecolumn:
        if route.value == 'Responsible Route':
            continue
        if route.value in Gordon:
            pos = Gordon.index(route.value)
            worksheet['CV' + str(i)].value = 'Gordon'
            i += 1
        elif route.value in VA:
            pos = VA.index(route.value)
            worksheet['CV' + str(i)].value = 'Vinny A'
            i += 1
        elif route.value in VP:
            pos = VP.index(route.value)
            worksheet['CV' + str(i)].value = 'Vinny P'
            i += 1
        elif route.value in Pete:
            pos = Pete.index(route.value)
            worksheet['CV' + str(i)].value = 'Pete'
            i += 1
        elif route.value in Mike:
            pos = Mike.index(route.value)
            worksheet['CV' + str(i)].value = 'Mike'
            i += 1
        elif route.value not in Gordon or route.value not in VA or route.value not in VP or route.value not in Pete \
        or route.value not in Mike:
            worksheet['CV' + str(i)].value = 'Building'
            i += 1


    workbook.save(filename)
    newfilename = filename.strip(".xlsx")
    newfilename = newfilename + ".xls"
    os.rename('/home/MY NAME/'+filename, '/home/MY NAME/'+newfilename)

    return send_file(newfilename, attachment_filename='tdx.xls', as_attachment=True), os.remove ('/home/MY NAME/'+newfilename)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True, host = '0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: In what way are the answers to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9918646/how-to-convert-xls-to-xlsx) not satisfactory?

Comment: Hmm. So in that answer xlrd writes it to the new xlsx file and then rather than returning book1 (the new book), I would open it with openpyxl and then process it? It's making sense to me.

Comment: The code should be minimal. The supplied code has nothing to do with the actual question.

Comment: What do you mean? I was referring to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9919409/6464893 Wouldn't the body of that function be what i'm looking to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My recommendation: Use xlrd to read the values you need, and openpyxl to create a new xlsx workbook. You just need to be able to get all of the relevant info using xlrd.

The only thing you're doing which isn't just reading values from cells is selecting the "active" worksheet. I found [this Google Groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-excel/-e0UkBDMPHo) in a thread titled "xlrd: Get active sheet" which says to try using either the `.sheet_selected` attribute or the `.sheet_visible` attribute, with the following code for checking which works:

```
import xlrd
b = xlrd.open_workbook("vis.xls") # where vis.xls is your test file
for i, s in enumerate(b.sheets()):
    print(i, s.name, s.sheet_selected, s.sheet_visible)
```

It also notes:

> These two attributes are documented in `sheet.py` in the dict `_WINDOW_2`
>   which starts at about line 2. `sheet_visible` is probably what you want.
>   Ignore the MS docs which show this bit as undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Best thing is to pipe the XLS file through OpenOffice / LibreOffice in [headless mode](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/53173/libreoffice-444-and-the-headless-install/) to do the conversion and then load the file in Python for processing.

Comment: sounds a bit overkill (you're invoking a 300MB+ framekwork) since a python library already exist for parsing xls

Comment: It's not overkill, it's a single line in a shell.