# Write data into existing excel file and making summary table

Tags: python, excel

I have to write some data into existing xls file.(i should say that im working on unix and couldnt use windows)
I prefer work with python and have tried some libraries like xlwt, openpyxl, xlutils.

Its not working, cause there is some filter in my xls file. After rewriting this file filter is dissapearing. But i still need this filter.

Could some one tell me about options that i have.
help, please!

Example:

```
from xlutils.copy import copy
from xlrd import open_workbook
from xlwt import easyxf
start_row=0
rb=open_workbook('file.xls')
r_sheet=rb.sheet_by_index(1)

wb=copy(rb)
w_sheet=wb.get_sheet(1)
for row_index in range(start_row, r_sheet.nrows):
    row=r_sheet.row_values(row_index)
    call_index=0
    for c_el in row:
        value=r_sheet.cell(row_index, call_index).value
        w_sheet.write(row_index, call_index, value)
        call_index+=1
wb.save('file.out.xls');
```

I also tried:
    import xlrd
    from openpyxl import Workbook
    import unicodedata

```
rb=xlrd.open_workbook('file.xls')
sheet=rb.sheet_by_index(0)
wb=Workbook()
ws1=wb.create_sheet("Results", 0)

for rownum in range(sheet.nrows):
    row=sheet.row_values(rownum)
    arr=[]
    for c_el in row:
        arr.append(c_el)
    ws1.append(arr)

ws2=wb.create_sheet("Common", 1)
sheet=rb.sheet_by_index(1)

for rownum in range(sheet.nrows):
    row=sheet.row_values(rownum)
    arr=[]
    for c_el in row:
        arr.append(c_el)

    ws2.append(arr)


ws2.auto_filter.ref=["A1:A15", "B1:B15"]
#ws['A1']=42

#ws.append([1,2,3])

wb.save('sample.xls')
```

The problem is still exist. Ok, ill try to find machine running on windows, but i have to admit something else: 
There is some rows like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zu5Jn.jpg)

Ive understood what i was doing wrong, but i still need help. 
First of all, i have one sheet that contains some values
Second sheet contains summary table!!!
If i try to copy this worksheet it did wrong.

So, the question is : how could i make summary table from first sheet?

Comment: Plz provide some code and what have you tried so far. Check here  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Also check here, it may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942889/reading-parsing-excel-xls-files-with-python

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your existing excel file has two columns (date and number).
This is how you will append additional rows using openpyxl.

```
import openpyxl
import datetime

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('existing_data_file.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

a = sheet.get_highest_row()
sheet.cell(row=a,column=0).value=datetime.date.today()
sheet.cell(row=a,column=1).value=30378

wb.save('existing_data_file.xlsx')
```

Comment: openpyxl doesnt support xls. im getting an exception.

Comment: You can pipe the XLS file through OpenOffice / LibreOffice in headless mode to do the conversion and then load the file in Python for processing.

Comment: Read this: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/2641/convert-to-command-line-parameter/

Comment: Read this one as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9918646/how-to-convert-xls-to-xlsx

Comment: it ll break filter in the book:(

Comment: Ive tried as you told me: with convertation file into xlsx format and without it. It always breaks filters in the target file.:(

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, I would suggest you take a look at using the `win32com.client` approach. This allows you to interact with your spreadsheet using Excel itself. This will ensure that any existing filters, images, tables, macros etc should be preserved.

The following example opens an XLS file adds one entry and saves the whole workbook as a different XLS formatted file:

```
import win32com.client as win32
import os


excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(r'input.xls')
ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

# Write a value at A1
ws.Range("A1").Value = "Hello World"

excel.DisplayAlerts = False     # Allow file overwrite
wb.SaveAs(r'sample.xls', FileFormat=56)
excel.Application.Quit()
```

Note, make sure you add full paths to your input and output files.