# Convert XLSX to XLS and Preserve hidden rows

Tags: python, excel, xlsx, xls, pyexcel

I am using the Python solution from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43325725/2893712) to convert an XLSX file to XLS however this ignores the rows I already have hidden. Is there a way to have this only copy the rows that are visible in my source Xlsx file?

Here is my code:

```
import pyexcel as p
p.save_book_as(file_name='Source.xlsx', dest_file_name='Destination.xls')
```

Comment: up-voting it as this is a genuine pyexcel related question.

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer**

Please use `skip_hidden_row_and_column=True` as in [pyexcel-xlsx test code](https://github.com/pyexcel/pyexcel-xlsx/blob/master/tests/test_hidden.py#L8):

```
p.save_book_as(file_name='Source.xlsx', 
               library='pyexcel-xlsx',  # <--- note 1
               skip_hidden_row_and_column=True,  # <--- note 2
               dest_file_name='Destination.xls')
```

To get `pyexcel-xlsx`, you can use `pip`:

```
pip install pyexcel-xlsx
```

**Explanation/Long Answer**

1. pyexcel-xls(xlrd) [does not support hidden rows for xlsx format](https://github.com/pyexcel/pyexcel-xls) but xls. That's why note 1 ask pyexcel to use pyexcel-xlsx to read the xlsx file instead.
2. And this flag was noted in [pyexcel-xlsx README](https://github.com/pyexcel/pyexcel-xlsx), `True` means to ignore hidden rows.

Why `library`? It is specific for `save_as`, `save_book_as`, `isave_as` and `isave_book_as`. In these functions, a reader and a writer were involved to finish the function. `library` tells pyexcel to use a specific library to read a file whereas `dest_library` tells pyexcel to write a file.

These have been documented, for example [save_as](http://pyexcel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/pyexcel.save_as.html#pyexcel.save_as) and please find *library* in the page.

Comment: I keep getting `pyexcel.exceptions.UnknownParameters: Please check if there were typos in function parameters: {'file_name': '<<FILENAME>>'}. Otherwise unrecognized parameters were given.`

Comment: Reproduced here. Checking it

Comment: My apologies. I have updated the code above. I, myself was confused about the `source_library` and `library`. `source_library` meant to be the data source library, while `library` meant to be io library.