# Decompress .xls file in python

Tags: python, excel, compression, unzip, zip

I'm searching for a method to decompress/unzip .xls files in python. By opening Excel files with 7-Zip you can see the directories I'd like to extract.

I already tried renaming the Excel to ".zip" and then extracting it

```
myExcelFile = zipfile.ZipFile("myExcel.zip") 
myExcelFile.extractall()
```

but it throws

```
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

[.xls in 7-Zip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogbAE.png)

Comment: Works fine for me. You do not have to rename the file, btw.

Comment: Can you share your Excel file?

Comment: It would be better if you shared the one that you are having problems with but you can try [this one](https://www.gonduana.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Excel-2010.xlsx) I found in the Internet.

Comment: It seems to me all you want to do is open an XLSX file

Comment: It's working for .xlsx but not for .xls
Sorry, didn't mention that
It's company data so I can't share it :(

Comment: @Goyo I added a picture of the Excel opened in 7-Zip. It does not recognize the directories

Comment: .xls files use the [BIFF](http://sc.openoffice.org/excelfileformat.pdf) format. .xlsx files use [Office Open XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML), which is a zipped XML format. BIFF is not a zipped format; files using that format are not recognized by zip libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> .xls files use the BIFF format. .xlsx files use Office Open XML, which is a zipped XML format. BIFF is not a zipped format; files using that format are not recognized by zip libraries. – shmee

a conversion to .xlsx is the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9918646/how-to-convert-xls-to-xlsx)

```
import win32com.client as win32
fname = "full+path+to+xls_file"
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(fname)

wb.SaveAs(fname+"x", FileFormat = 51)    #FileFormat = 51 is for .xlsx extension
wb.Close()                               #FileFormat = 56 is for .xls extension
excel.Application.Quit()
```