# Is it possible in Python to convert the below strange .XLS file, which is actually in some HTML/XML format to .XLSX?

Tags: python, excel, xml, mime, webarchive

Quite puzzled by the format of these .xls files as they are not really .xls files, I've put the first few lines of the file below for reference, [full file here](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1018724/000119312510164083/Financial_Report.xls).

Converting normal .xls is no problem with `p.save_book_as(file_name=fname, dest_file_name=fname+'x')`.

I would like to convert to .xlsx in bulk with python, is this even possible with the below format?

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Document-Type: Workbook
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="----=_NextPart_86ab7b61_9054_45ca_a3a6_49bc8ebc61db"

This document is a Single File Web Page, also known as a Web Archive file.  If you are seeing this message, your browser or editor doesn't support Web Archive files.  Please download a browser that supports Web Archive, such as Microsoft Internet Explorer.

------=_NextPart_86ab7b61_9054_45ca_a3a6_49bc8ebc61db
Content-Location: file:///C:/86ab7b61_9054_45ca_a3a6_49bc8ebc61db/Workbook.html
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"

<html xmlns:v=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns=3D"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<head>
<meta name=3D"Excel Workbook Frameset">

<meta name=3DProgId content=3DExcel.Sheet>
<link rel=3DFile-List href=3D"Worksheets/filelist.xml">

<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <x:ExcelWorkbook>
  <x:ExcelWorksheets>
   <x:ExcelWorksheet>
```

Comment: How did you obtain this file?

Comment: Link to full file is above in question, it is a financial statement for Amazon available on the SEC's website. For some reason the SEC went from using normal XLS format for a few years, then this HTML/XLS format for a couple of years then onto XLSX for all their financial statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be "[Excel compatible HTML](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=65828)".
While I do not know a pure python converter, you could try to use excel as an external converter, i.e. open those files and save them to xlsx, as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9918646/how-to-convert-xls-to-xlsx) and copied below. This requires the pywin32 package, to access excel remotely.

```
import win32com.client as win32
fname = "full+path+to+xls_file"
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(fname)

wb.SaveAs(fname+"x", FileFormat = 51)    #FileFormat = 51 is for .xlsx extension
wb.Close()                               #FileFormat = 56 is for .xls extension
excel.Application.Quit()
```