# Converting xls files to xlsx using python

Tags: python, excel, file-conversion

I've got loads of 97-2003 Excel xls files i wanna bulk convert to xlsx.

I found [the `xls2xlsx` documentation](https://pypi.org/project/xls2xlsx/) but can't seem to get it to work.

I have tried googling the errors and searching but to no avail.

```py
import os

from xls2xlsx import XLS2XLSX


directory = 'C:\\Users\\Python Scripts\\convertXLStoXLSX\\'

for filename in os.listdir(directory):

    if filename.endswith(".xls"):
        x2x = XLS2XLSX(filename)
        x2x.to_xlsx(filename)
    else:
        continue
```

I am getting the error message:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'GuessedAtParserWarning' from 'bs4' (C:\Users\wf5931\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py)
```

Comment: Have you installed BeautifulSoup?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to convert xls to xlsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9918646/how-to-convert-xls-to-xlsx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("file.xls")
df.to_excel("file.xlsx")
```

Comment: THANKS! SO easy. 

All the best

Comment: Is there a way to get Panda to remember things like cell formatting, dropdown columns, locked columns, and etc? It is removing all of that for me :\

Comment: Not sure why this is an answer, pandas will obviously remove all formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Just including my finished code for future use by others which uses pandas - worked almost instantly

import os
import pandas as pd

```
directory = 'C:\\Users\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\convertXLStoXLSX\\'

for filename in os.listdir(directory):

    if filename.endswith(".xls"):
        df = pd.read_excel(filename)
        df.to_excel(filename + ".xlsx")
```