# Convert XLS files to XLSX in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My objective is to take a large number of XLS files and convert them to XLSX. I can do it one line at a time with a simple operation, or do a large number of files in a batch if anyone knows a way.

[I attempted to use most of the solutions on this Stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9918646/how-to-convert-xls-to-xlsx/9919409#9919409), but it seems they no longer work, or apply. It is 9 years old, so a modern solution may be needed.

Code I tried:

```
p.save_book_as(file_name='C://Users//user1//Downloads//oldfile.xls',
           dest_file_name='C://Users//user1//Downloads//oldfile.xlsx')
```

But this resulted in an error:

```
 raise XLRDError('Unsupported format, or corrupt file: ' + msg)
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'<?xml ve'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Tablib](https://tablib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), as in:

```
with open('input.xls', 'r') as input:
    data = Dataset().load(input)
    with open('output.xlsx', 'wb') as output:
        output.write(data.export('xlsx'))
```

Not sure if it supports your versions of xls/xlsx, though.

Comment: It says for some reason "Dataset()" is not recognized. Is there an alternative solution?

Comment: @user18139 What is the exact wording of the error? And what is "is", the library? I mean, where does the error come from?