# How to convert xls excel files to xlsx files using xlrd and openpyxl libraries in python

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlrd

I have tried the following code to convert xls excel files to xlsx files using xlrd and openpyxl libraries in python since openpyxl does not read xls files.

```
import xlrd
import openpyxl


excel_files = ['one.xls', 'two.xls', 'three.xls', 'four.xls', 'five.xls', 'six.xls']


for excel_file in excel_files:

    
    wb_old = xlrd.open_workbook(excel_file)

    
    wb_new = openpyxl.Workbook()

    
    ws_new = wb_new.active
    for ws_old in wb_old.sheets():
        for row in range(ws_old.nrows):
            for col in range(ws_old.ncols):
                ws_new.cell(row=row, column=col).value = ws_old.cell(row=row, column=col).value

    
    wb_new.save(excel_file.replace('.xls', '.xlsx'))
```

The problem is that I get the following error: TypeError: cell() got an unexpected keyword argument 'row'. This error is in reference to this line of code: `ws_new.cell(row=row, column=col).value = ws_old.cell(row=row, column=col).value`

Can someone help me on how to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to convert xls to xlsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9918646/how-to-convert-xls-to-xlsx)

Comment: Looks like you haven't read the documentation for `xlrd`.

Answer (score 1):

The line in your code

```
ws_new.cell(row=row, column=col).value = ws_old.cell(row=row, column=col).value
```

causes issues for two reasons;

1. Xlrd doesn't use 'row=' & 'column=', you just add the row and column co-ordinate in brackets like `(0, 0)`. This is the cause of the error message you see.
2. Openpyxl row and column counts start at 1 while xlrd starts at 0. Therefore on your first iteration the values for `row=` and `column=` in the Openpyxl cell being 0 will fail.

You'd need to change that line to something like this;

```
ws_new.cell(row=row+1, column=col+1).value = ws_old.cell(row, col).value
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you @Moken