# How to save an Excel worksheet as CSV

Tags: python, excel, csv

I want to write a Python script that reads in an Excel spreadsheet and saves some of its worksheets as CSV files.

How can I do this?

I have found [third-party modules](http://www.python-excel.org/) for reading and writing Excel files from Python, but as far as I can tell, they can only save files in Excel (i.e. *.xls) format.  If I'm wrong here, some example code showing how to do what I'm trying to do with these modules would be appreciated.

I also came across [one solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730428/why-cant-i-save-as-an-excel-file-from-my-python-code) that I can't quite understand, but seems to be Windows-specific, and therefore would not help me anyway, since I want to do this in Unix.  At any rate, it's not clear to me that this solution can be extended to do what I want to do, even under Windows.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The most basic examples using the two libraries described line by line:

1. Open the xls workbook
2. Reference the first spreadsheet
3. Open in binary write the target csv file
4. Create the default csv writer object
5. Loop over all the rows of the first spreadsheet
6. Dump the rows into the csv

---

```
import xlrd
import csv

with xlrd.open_workbook('a_file.xls') as wb:
    sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)  # or wb.sheet_by_name('name_of_the_sheet_here')
    with open('a_file.csv', 'wb') as f:   # open('a_file.csv', 'w', newline="") for python 3
        c = csv.writer(f)
        for r in range(sh.nrows):
            c.writerow(sh.row_values(r))
```

---

```
import openpyxl
import csv

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
sh = wb.active
with open('test.csv', 'wb') as f:  # open('test.csv', 'w', newline="") for python 3
    c = csv.writer(f)
    for r in sh.rows:
        c.writerow([cell.value for cell in r])
```

Comment: To evaluate the Excel formulas with `openpyxl` : `wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx', data_only=True)`

Comment: @Zeugma how can I write this csv back to a folder?  (In my case aws s3) I keep getting AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'save'

Answer (score 18):

Using `pandas` will be a bit shorter:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('my_file', sheet_name='my_sheet_name')  # sheet_name is optional
df.to_csv('output_file_name', index=False)  # index=False prevents pandas from writing a row index to the CSV.

# oneliner
pd.read_excel('my_file', sheetname='my_sheet_name').to_csv('output_file_name', index=False)
```

Comment: I don't trust pandas to do this. It's been converting all my leading zeros.

Comment: Can you give some more details?

Comment: This implementation works perfectly fine for my scenario, just change `sheetname` to `sheet_name` as it's a typo.

Comment: @rrs why not use `pd.read_excel('my_file', dtype=str)` ? more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41662442/3517025)

Answer (score 16):

**As of December 2021 and Python 3:**

The `openpyxl` API has changed sufficiently (see https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html) that I have updated this part of the answer by @Boud (now @Zeugma?), as follows:

```py
import openpyxl
import csv

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
sh = wb.active # was .get_active_sheet()
with open('test.csv', 'w', newline="") as file_handle:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(file_handle)
    for row in sh.iter_rows(): # generator; was sh.rows
        csv_writer.writerow([cell.value for cell in row])
```

@Leonid made some helpful comments - in particular:

`csv.writer` provides some additional options e.g. custom delimiter:

```py
csv_writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter='|', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```

HTH

Comment: A couple of typos here.  The "with" needs "as f" on the end, and "sh.iter_rows" should be "sh.iter_rows()"  Otherwise, works well, thanks!

Comment: @eakst7 Huge thanks - can you believe I typed it out - now fixed - glad it helped.

Comment: Thanks, that was useful. Two comments from me: 1. `pylama` does not like single-letter variable names and the call to `csv.writer` provides additional options (such as custom delimiter) which would be cool to highlight. For example: `csv_writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter='|', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)`

Comment: @Leonid Thanks so much - updated as per your helpful comments!

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`xlrd`](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html)  or [`openpyxl`](http://packages.python.org/openpyxl/)module to read xls or xlsx documents respectively, and the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module to write.

Alternately, if using [Jython](http://jython.org/), you can use the [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) library to read either `.xls` or `.xlsx`, and the native CSV module will still be available.

Comment: And if you need to read .xlsx files use [openpyxl](http://packages.python.org/openpyxl/).

Comment: I prefer [`xlsxrd`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/python-excel/J4pKxEWGOd0/-Nm23guVH84J) to read `.xlsx` files.  At some point, it will be merged into `xlrd`.

Answer (score 0):

First read your Excel spreadsheet into Pandas. The code below will import your Excel spreadsheet into Pandas as an `OrderedDict` which contains all of your worksheets as `DataFrames`. Then, simply use the `worksheet_name` as a key to access specific worksheet as a `DataFrame` and save only the required worksheet as a `csv` file by using `df.to_csv()`. Hope this will work in your case.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('YourExcel.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
df['worksheet_name'].to_csv('output.csv')
```