# Python pandas: how to specify data types when reading an Excel file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am importing an excel file into a pandas dataframe with the `pandas.read_excel()` function.

One of the columns is the primary key of the table: it's all numbers, but it's stored as text (the little green triangle in the top left of the Excel cells confirms this).

However, when I import the file into a pandas dataframe, the column gets imported as a float. This means that, for example, '0614' becomes 614.

Is there a way to specify the datatype when importing a column? I understand this is possible when importing CSV files but couldn't find anything in the syntax of `read_excel()`.

The only solution I can think of is to add an arbitrary letter at the beginning of the text (converting '0614' into 'A0614') in Excel, to make sure the column is imported as text, and then chopping off the 'A' in python, so I can match it to other tables I am importing from SQL.

Answer (score 198, accepted):

You just specify converters.  I created an excel spreadsheet of the following structure:

```
names   ages
bob     05
tom     4
suzy    3
```

Where the "ages" column is formatted as strings.  To load:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx',sheetname='Sheet1',header=0,converters={'names':str,'ages':str})
>>> df
       names ages
   0   bob   05
   1   tom   4
   2   suzy  3
```

Comment: I had understood 'converters' specified a function to apply to the column. evidently I was wrong - thank you for pointing this out, it's very useful!

Comment: Where can I find the list of allowable converter functions? 
I see `str` here, but presumably there's `int` and a few more besides - is there a link anywhere to the source docs that enumerates the possible converter functions available?

Comment: I have not found a list either.  Since "converters" accepts functions, I suspect that your imagination is the limit, just so you keep within the bounds of the "converters" functionality (i.e. it was designed to use functions that require only one input variable!).

Comment: Oddly, when I set a column name to `str` in the `converters` dict and then print `df.dtypes`, the type for that column is set to `object` not `str`. Any ideas? Is it even important?

Comment: @mhyousefi  This is not important (on the surface at least).  When setting column types as strings Pandas refers to them as objects.  See HYRY's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018654/strings-in-a-dataframe-but-dtype-is-object)

Answer (score 106):

Starting with `v0.20.0`, the `dtype` keyword argument in [`read_excel()`](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas.read_excel) function could be used to specify the data types that needs to be applied to the columns just like it exists for  [`read_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) case.

Using `converters` and `dtype` arguments together on the same column name would lead to the latter getting shadowed and the former gaining preferance.

---

1) Inorder for it to not interpret the `dtypes` but rather pass all the contents of it's columns as they were originally in the file before, we could set this arg to `str` or `object` so that we don't mess up our data. (one such case would be leading zeros in numbers which would be lost otherwise)

```
pd.read_excel('file_name.xlsx', dtype=str)            # (or) dtype=object
```

2) It even supports a dict mapping wherein the `keys` constitute the column names and `values` it's respective data type to be set especially when you want to alter the `dtype` for a subset of all the columns.

```
# Assuming data types for `a` and `b` columns to be altered
pd.read_excel('file_name.xlsx', dtype={'a': np.float64, 'b': np.int32})
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as "converters" seem to convert data AFTER reading it as a different type. This leads to information loss ("001" will be read as int("001")="1" and then converted to str. But "001" != "1") . At least that is what happended in my case, correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, this is the more intuitive solution for me

Comment: After trying many possibilities, this one worked for me. Thank you very much!

Comment: OMG! This is THE right answer! I had a stupid number that was 7E+19 giving me an overflow error when Python tried to put it in an SQL Integer, and no other method was able to deal with this. I needed to set `dtype=str` and that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 13):

In case if you are not aware of the number and name of columns in dataframe then this method can be handy:

```
column_list = []
df_column = pd.read_excel(file_name, 'Sheet1').columns
for i in df_column:
    column_list.append(i)
converter = {col: str for col in column_list} 
df_actual = pd.read_excel(file_name, converters=converter)
```

where column_list is the list of your column names.

Comment: Just wonder if `df = df.astype(str)` would not be better (simpler).

Comment: Why do you create a list first? Maybe more efficient to use:

`conv = {x:str for x in pd.read_excel(fn,sheet_name='sheet1').columns}` and then
 `df = pd.read_excel(fn,sheet_name='sheet1',converters=conv)`

Answer (score 12):

If you are able to read the excel file correctly and only the integer values are not showing up. you can specify like this.

```
df = pd.read_excel('my.xlsx',sheetname='Sheet1', engine="openpyxl", dtype=str)
```

this should change your integer values into a string and show in dataframe

Answer (score 10):

The read_excel() function has a converters argument, where you can apply functions to input in certain columns.  You can use this to keep them as strings.
[Documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html):

> Dict of functions for converting values in certain columns. Keys can either be integers or column labels, values are functions that take one input argument, the Excel cell content, and return the transformed content.

Example code:

```
pandas.read_excel(my_file, converters = {my_str_column: str})
```

Comment: If we are not aware of number of columns present in the sheet, is there any way to apply it to every column while reading?

Comment: Got the solution:
`converters = {col: str for col in column_list}
df = pd.read_excel('some_excelfile.xls', converters=converters)`

Comment: can you do it by index or do you need the name? e.g, i'm reading my file in without headers.

Comment: @rrs, you can just use an integer as the key instead of the column name.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't know the column names and you want to specify **str** data type to all columns:

```
table = pd.read_excel("path_to_filename")
cols = table.columns
conv = dict(zip(cols ,[str] * len(cols)))
table = pd.read_excel("path_to_filename", converters=conv)
```

Comment: Also It might be useful to add `nrows=1` in the first `read_excel` call to avoid having to read the whole excel table only to get the headers.

Answer (score 4):

If your key has a fixed number of digits, you *should* probably store as text rather than as numeric data. You can use the `converters` argument or `read_excel` for this.

Or, if this does not work, just manipulate your data once it's read into your dataframe:

```
df['key_zfill'] = df['key'].astype(str).str.zfill(4)

  names   key key_zfill
0   abc     5      0005
1   def  4962      4962
2   ghi   300      0300
3   jkl    14      0014
4   mno    20      0020
```

Answer (score 2):

`converters` or `dtype` won't always help. Especially for date/time and duration (ideally a mix of both...), post-processing is necessary. In such cases, reading the Excel file's content to a built-in type and create the DataFrame from that can be an option.

Here's an [example file](https://github.com/MrFuppes/pydatetimetut/blob/main/pandas/durations_from_Excel_ex.xlsx). The "duration" column contains duration values in HH:MM:SS and invalid values "-".

[image: excel_sample]

If the hour is less than 24, Excel formats the entry to a time, otherwise a duration. We want dtype `timedelta` for the whole column in the DataFrame. But `pandas` messes up the import:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("path-to-file")

df.duration
# 0               12:30:00
# 1    1900-01-01 00:30:00
# 2                      -
# 3    1900-01-01 23:55:01
# Name: duration, dtype: object

[type(i) for i in df.duration]
# [datetime.time, datetime.datetime, str, datetime.datetime]
```

Now we have datetime.datetime and datetime.time objects, and [it's difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70860439/10197418) to get back duration (timedelta)! You could do it directly with a `converter`, but that does not make it less difficult.

Here, I found it to be actually easier to use the excel loader engine directly:

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('path-to-file')

sheet = wb['Tests'] # adjust sheet name, this is for the demo file
data = list(sheet.values) # a list of tuples, one tuple for each row
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0]) # first tuple is column names

df['duration']
# 0           12:30:00
# 1     1 day, 0:30:00
# 2                  -
# 3    1 day, 23:55:01
# Name: duration, dtype: object

[type(i) for i in df['duration']]
# [datetime.time, datetime.timedelta, str, datetime.timedelta]
```

So now we already have some timedelta objects! The conversion of the others to timedelta can be done as simple as

```py
df['duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(df.duration.astype(str), errors='coerce')
df['duration']
# 0   0 days 12:30:00
# 1   1 days 00:30:00
# 2               NaT
# 3   1 days 23:55:01
# Name: duration, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: This issue may apply as well when the dtype in excel is 'Special'