# Pandas Read_Excel Datetime Converter

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Using Python 3.6 and Pandas 0.19.2: How do you read in an excel file and change a column to datetime straight from `read_excel`? Similar to [This Question about converters and dtypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32591466/python-pandas-how-to-specify-data-types-when-reading-an-excel-file). But I want to read in a certain column as `datetime`

I want to change this:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np

file = 'PATH_HERE'

df1 = pd.read_excel(file)

df1['COLUMN'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['COLUMN']) # <--- Line to get rid of
```

into something like:
`df1 = pd.read_excel(file, dtypes= {'COLUMN': datetime})`

The code does not error, but in my example, `COLUMN` is still a dtype of `int64` after calling `print(df1['COLUMN'].dtype)`

I have tried using `np.datetime64` instead of `datetime`. I have also tried using  `converters=` instead of `dtypes=` but to no avail. This may be nit picky, but would be a nice feature to implement in my code.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Typically reading excel sheets will use the dtypes defined in the excel sheets but you cannot specify the dtypes like in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) for example. You can provide a [`converters`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas.read_excel) arg for which you can pass a dict of the column and func to call to convert the column:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(file, converters= {'COLUMN': pd.to_datetime})
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way to read in an excel file and change a column to datetime straight from `read_excel` is as follows;

```
import pandas as pd

file = 'PATH_HERE'

df1 = pd.read_excel(file, parse_dates=['COLUMN'])
```

For reference, I am using python 3.8.3

Answer (score 1):

`read_excel` supports `dtype`, just as `read_csv`, as of this writing:

```
import datetime

import pandas as pd


xlsx = pd.ExcelFile('path...')
df = pd.read_excel(xlsx, dtype={'column_name': datetime.datetime})
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html