# How to read time from .xlsx in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, time, xlsx

I'm trying to use Pandas to read a .xlsx file that contains two columns: time duration (**mm:ss.cs**) and date (**mm/dd/yyyy**):

```
Time    Date
1:28.01 1/11/2020
1:29.02 2/29/2020
2:14.42 11/17/2017
1:44.16 6/30/2019
1:47.25 5/19/2019
1:57.16 1/11/2020
1:20.82 1/12/2020
1:25.18 3/2/2019
1:52.00 12/17/2017
1:34.82 5/19/2019
1:38.90 6/29/2019
1:35.83 11/16/2019
1:39.99 1/13/2019
1:43.04 3/3/2019
1:51.00 10/13/2018
2:52.83 1/12/2020
41.55   3/1/2020
41.71   11/16/2019
42.79   4/13/2019
44.29   10/13/2019
45.18   1/13/2019
45.54   12/16/2018
45.90   3/3/2019
50.71   10/14/2018
1:04.01 1/21/2018
1:04.58 10/15/2017
1:06.10 11/18/2017
48.42   6/29/2019
49.88   6/1/2019
50.17   7/7/2019
1:00.75 6/2/2018
53.81   1/12/2020
55.71   10/13/2019
59.95   1/12/2019
1:06.20 7/7/2019
1:08.09 5/19/2019
50.56   12/15/2018
1:14.41 12/17/2017
55.93   6/1/2019
1:16.87 6/2/2018
33.60   2/29/2020
34.94   1/11/2020
35.28   11/16/2019
38.08   1/12/2019
38.87   3/3/2019
40.12   12/16/2018
40.40   10/13/2018
49.14   12/16/2017
49.33   1/20/2018
52.69   11/17/2017
53.26   10/14/2017
43.40   7/7/2019
43.84   6/1/2019
46.63   6/2/2018
47.03   6/30/2019
```

I simply called `read_excel()`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r'test.xlsx')
```

After execution, df is:

```
Time    Date
0   1900-02-02 12:01:28.010000  1/11/2020
1   1900-02-02 12:01:47.250000  5/19/2019
2   1900-02-02 12:01:57.160000  1/11/2020
3   1900-02-02 12:01:20.820000  1/12/2020
4   1900-02-02 12:01:25.180000  3/2/2019
5   1900-02-02 12:01:52     12/17/2017
6   1900-02-02 12:01:34.820000  5/19/2019
7   1900-02-02 12:01:29.020000  2/29/2020
8   1900-02-02 12:02:14.420000  11/17/2017
9   1900-02-02 12:01:44.160000  6/30/2019
10  1900-02-02 12:01:38.900000  6/29/2019
11  1900-02-02 12:01:35.830000  11/16/2019
12  1900-02-02 12:01:39.990000  1/13/2019
13  1900-02-02 12:01:43.040000  3/3/2019
14  1900-02-02 12:01:51     10/13/2018
15  1900-02-02 12:02:52.830000  1/12/2020
16  33.50048090277778   3/1/2020
17  33.50048275462963   11/16/2019
18  33.50049525462963   4/13/2019
19  33.50051261574074   10/13/2019
20  33.50052291666667   1/13/2019
21  33.50052708333333   12/16/2018
22  33.50053125     3/3/2019
23  33.500586921296296  10/14/2018
24  1900-02-02 12:01:04.010000  1/21/2018
25  1900-02-02 12:01:04.580000  10/15/2017
26  1900-02-02 12:01:06.100000  11/18/2017
27  33.500560416666666  6/29/2019
28  33.50057731481481   6/1/2019
29  33.5005806712963    7/7/2019
30  1900-02-02 12:01:00.750000  6/2/2018
31  33.500622800925925  1/12/2020
32  33.500644791666666  10/13/2019
33  33.50069386574074   1/12/2019
34  1900-02-02 12:01:06.200000  7/7/2019
35  1900-02-02 12:01:08.090000  5/19/2019
36  33.50058518518519   12/15/2018
37  1900-02-02 12:01:14.410000  12/17/2017
38  33.50064733796296   6/1/2019
39  1900-02-02 12:01:16.870000  6/2/2018
40  33.50038888888889   2/29/2020
41  33.50040439814815   1/11/2020
42  33.50040833333333   11/16/2019
43  33.50044074074074   1/12/2019
44  33.50044988425926   3/3/2019
45  33.50046435185185   12/16/2018
46  33.50046759259259   10/13/2018
47  33.50056875     12/16/2017
48  33.500570949074074  1/20/2018
49  33.50060983796296   11/17/2017
50  33.50061643518519   10/14/2017
51  33.50050231481482   7/7/2019
52  33.500507407407405  6/1/2019
53  33.500539699074075  6/2/2018
54  33.500544328703704  6/30/2019
```

Some of the times were converted by add prefix "1900-02-02 12:", and some were changed to "33.5xxxxxxxx" which appeared to be totally messed up.

I tried to read Time as strings but got the same df:

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'test.xlsx', dtype={'Time':str})
```

So my question: how can I read the Time values correctly - keep their original format, convert them to miliseconds or whatever time format that Python recognizes?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42958217/pandas-read-excel-datetime-converter

Answer (score 0):

I would read the data with `Time` as string as you did, and parse the string:

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'test.xlsx', dtype={'Time':str})

# parse the string time
min_sec = ('0:' + df.Time).str.extract('(?P<min>\d+):(?P<sec>[\d\.]+)$').astype(float)

# convert to timedelta
df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(min_sec['min'] * 60 + min_sec['sec'], unit='s')
```

Output:

```
# min_sec
    min    sec
0   1.0  28.01
1   1.0  29.02
2   2.0  14.42
3   1.0  44.16
4   1.0  47.25
5   1.0  57.16
6   1.0  20.82
7   1.0  25.18
8   1.0  52.00
9   1.0  34.82
10  1.0  38.90
11  1.0  35.83
12  1.0  39.99
13  1.0  43.04
14  1.0  51.00
15  2.0  52.83
16  0.0  41.55
17  0.0  41.71
18  0.0  42.79
19  0.0  44.29

# df
             Time        Date
0 00:01:28.010000   1/11/2020
1 00:01:29.020000   2/29/2020
2 00:02:14.420000  11/17/2017
3 00:01:44.160000   6/30/2019
4 00:01:47.250000   5/19/2019
```

Comment: Works as expected. Thank you.