# Preserving dataframe column with lists of strings in CSV format

Tags: python, excel, string, dataframe, csv

This may sound convoluted, but I'm trying. If I'm not clear, please let me know and I will update this.

I have a data frame (Excel) made up of tweets and accompanying data sent by US congressmembers. One of these columns ("to") is composed of lists of strings (see image below).

[image]

I am trying to preserve these lists in this "to" column while saving the whole data frame as a CSV file, such that all these names are still recognized as a list of strings within the CSV file. The reason I need to save it in this format is that I'm using existing code to run some analyses on this data, and that code requires it in CSV format. The code I'm trying to run comes from [this Github Repository project](https://github.com/computational-culture-lab/comp-acculturation). In this code (see the `measure.py` document), the authors state I should be able to include a list of user strings in the from column (See image below -- I believe they mean the "to" not "from" column, but I've tried it both ways with the same result).

[image]

The code works with the CSV file if there is only one name in each cell of the "to" column, but it hasn't worked if there are multiple names/strings in the cell. I could be wrong, but it seems that the lists of strings confuse the code when saved as a CSV file. I have tried to get help from the [github repository contributors](https://github.com/computational-culture-lab/comp-acculturation/issues/4), but with no response. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using pandas? Convert from excel to pandas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44070938/python-convert-excel-data-into-dataframes and then use ```df.to_csv```?

Comment: @bonfab, I haven't used pandas (I'm not very familiar with python), but I tried to write the dataframe to a csv file in R. I was able to do that, but the code still didn't work. Do you think it might work better with pandas?

Comment: @Iwe pandas allows lists to be written to csv. They would look like ```"[a, b, c]"``` in the csv file.