# Reading Excel file to Python fails due to number formatted as text

Tags: excel, pandas, openpyxl, xlrd, vba

I have a ton of Excel files that each have a column where numbers are formatted as text. Excel gives the error "the number in this cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe" - see the third column where the cells have a green triangle.

[image]

My goal is to open all of these files in Pandas **without** having to manually open each of them and convert the column to number. However, pd.read_excel() fails with the following `xlrd` error:

```
XLRDError: ZIP file contents not a known type of workbook
```

Unsurprisingly when I use `xlrd` directly: `wb = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)` I get the same error.

I also tried openpyxl: `wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)`, and it gives me this:

```
KeyError: "There is no item named 'xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels' in the archive"
```

I confirmed that the file is openable by both pandas (xlrd) and openpyxl if I manually convert the column to number in excel and re-save the workbook.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is there a chance you could upload a sample? I'm trying to produce the same error, but not quite getting it.

Comment: you've basically got to use "converters" while reading the excel into a dataframe. Read doc (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html)


question seems pretty similar to an earlier post.

(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32591466/python-pandas-how-to-specify-data-types-when-reading-an-excel-file).

Comment: Worth noting that the file is invalid because it's missing the workbook relationships file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "converters" while reading excel.
[Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html).

Eg.:

```
df = pd.read_excel('yourfile.xlsx',sheetname='sheetname',header=0,converters={ "% Chg" : str })
```