# Pandas ExcelFile read columns as string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know that you can specify data types when reading excels using `pd.read_excel` (as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32591466/python-pandas-how-to-specify-data-types-when-reading-an-excel-file)). Can you do the same using `pd.ExcelFile`?

I have the following code:

```
 if ".xls" in 
     xl = pd.ExcelFile(path + "\\" + name, )
     for sheet in xl.sheet_names:
         xl_parsed = xl.parse(sheet)
```

When parsing the sheet, some of the values in the columns are displayed in scientific notation. I don't know the column names before loading so I need to import everything as string. Ideally I would like to be able to do something like `xl_parsed = xl.parse(sheet, dtype = str)`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please make sure that you refer to [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.ExcelFile.parse.html) before asking. The accepted answer in the question you linked shows that `read_excel` takes a `converters` parameter. So does `pd.ExcelFile.parse`. Did you try it?

Comment: Although I should have read the end of your question more closely as that deals with something not covered by the docs. There was an issue about it [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/5891) which got closed but doesn't seem to have been resolved in any proper way. There is one approach in there that you might be able to adapt; open the Excel in xlrd, inspect the headers to get the names, and create a dictionary comprehension to then pass as `converters`. Kinda ugly.

Comment: @roganjosh thanks for the input, that's what i did! I'll post it as an answer

Comment: The solution you suggested is supported by the `parse` method although it is not mentioned explicitly on the documentation, so you can just use `xl_parsed = xl.parse(sheet, dtype=str)`

Answer (score 3):

If you would prefer a cleaner solution, I used the following:

```py
excel = pd.ExcelFile(path)
for sheet in excel.sheet_names:
    columns = excel.parse(sheet).columns
    converters = {column: str for column in columns}

    data = excel.parse(sheet, converters=converters)
```

Answer (score 1):

I went with roganjosh's suggestion - open the excel first, get column names and then pass as converter.

```
if ".xls" in name:
    xl = pd.ExcelFile(path)
    sheetCounter = 1
        for sheet in xl.sheet_names:
        ### Force to read as string ###
        column_list = []
        df_column = pd.read_excel(path, sheetCounter - 1).columns
        for i in df_column:
            column_list.append(i)
        converter = {col: str for col in column_list}
        ##################
        xl_parsed = xl.parse(sheet, converters=converter)
        sheetCounter = sheetCounter + 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `column_list` seems pointless, you can just use `df_column` directly. You can also use `for i, sheet in enumerate(xl.sheet_names):` instead of `sheetCounter`. I assume the `for sheet in ...` should be indented -4 spaces.