# Pandas problem with a column with mixed time and date time

Tags: python, excel, pandas, datetime, time

I have a column that came from Excel, that is supposed to contain durations (in hours) - example: `02:00:00` -
It works well if all this durations are less than 24:00 but if one is more than that, it appears in pandas as `1900-01-03 08:00:00` (so datetime)
as a result the datatype is dtype('O').

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'duration':[datetime.time(2, 0), datetime.time(2, 0),
       datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 3, 8, 0),
       datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 3, 8, 0),
       datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 3, 8, 0),
       datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 3, 8, 0),
       datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 3, 8, 0),
       datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 3, 8, 0), datetime.time(1, 0),
       datetime.time(1, 0)]})

# Output
    duration
0   02:00:00
1   02:00:00
2   1900-01-03 08:00:00
3   1900-01-03 08:00:00
4   1900-01-03 08:00:00
5   1900-01-03 08:00:00
6   1900-01-03 08:00:00
7   1900-01-03 08:00:00
8   01:00:00
9   01:00:00
```

But if I try to convert to either time or datetime I always get an error.

> **TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime**

Today if I don't fix this, all the duration greater than 24:00 are gone.

Comment: Could you edit the question to include the code which produces that type error?

Comment: If you try to get it to a datetime, maybe try to extract hour from it. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.hour.html

Comment: It would be very helpful if you provide your sample data, code your tried, and expected output.

Comment: just for the record, here's three related posts on SO, [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35579042/10197418), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63067926/10197418), [#3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34156830/10197418) - although the questions are not exactly the same, I think they go back to the same root. Imho, Python should not make the same mistake as Excel and think too much for the user ?! - just leave date/times as string if not specified otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies in the engine that reads the Excel file. It converts cells that have a certain format (e.g. `[h]:mm:ss` or `hh:mm:ss`) to `datetime.datetime` or `datetime.time` objects. Those then get transferred into the pandas DataFrame, so it's not actually a pandas problem.

Before you start hacking the excel reader engine, it might be easier to tackle the issue in Excel. Here's a small sample file;

[image]

You can download it [here](https://github.com/MrFuppes/pydatetimetut/raw/main/pandas/durations_from_Excel_ex.xlsx).
`duration` is auto-formatted by Excel, `duration_text` is what you get if you set the column format to 'text' *before* you enter the values, `duration_to_text` is what you get if you change the format to text *after* Excel auto-formatted the values (first column).

Now you have everything you need after import with pandas:

```
df = pd.read_excel('path_to_file')

df
              duration duration_text  duration_to_text
0             12:30:00      12:30:00          0.520833
1  1900-01-01 00:30:00      24:30:00          1.020833

# now you can parse to timedelta:
pd.to_timedelta(df['duration_text'], errors='coerce')
0   0 days 12:30:00
1   1 days 00:30:00
Name: duration_text, dtype: timedelta64[ns]

# or
pd.to_timedelta(df['duration_to_text'], unit='d', errors='coerce') 
0   0 days 12:29:59.999971200                     # note the precision issue ;-)
1   1 days 00:29:59.999971200
Name: duration_to_text, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

---

Another viable option could be to save the Excel file as a `csv` and import that to a pandas DataFrame. The sample xlsx used above would then look like [this](https://github.com/MrFuppes/pydatetimetut/raw/main/pandas/durations_from_Excel_ex.csv) for example.

---

If you have no other option than to re-process in pandas, an option could be to treat datetime.time objects and datetime.datetime objects specifically, e.g.

```
import datetime

# where you have datetime (incorrect from excel)
m = [isinstance(i, datetime.datetime) for i in df.duration]

# convert to timedelta where it's possible
df['timedelta'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['duration'].astype(str), errors='coerce')

# where you have datetime, some special treatment is needed...
df.loc[m, 'timedelta'] = df.loc[m, 'duration'].apply(lambda t: pd.Timestamp(str(t)) - pd.Timestamp('1899-12-31'))

df['timedelta'] 
0   0 days 12:30:00
1   1 days 00:30:00
Name: timedelta, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Yes that's true that the problem comes from the way the excel data is interpreted.
Unfortunately, I can't make changes in the excel.
There must be a way in Pandas to deal with this 2 different format in the same column, no ?

Comment: @didierseverac yes you *can* deal with it, but it's painful imho ;-) I'll add an option...

Comment: the loc gives me this error "ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable"

Comment: @didierseverac I've updated my answer to correctly handle NaT (can't use generator expression to derive `m`).

Comment: @didierseverac glad your issue is solved! I still wonder if this problem can be grabbed by the root, the excel reader engine ^^

Comment: Ideally, it would be best if when reading Excel, if it was possible to specify the datatype for each column (or even better, to force datatype only for some specifics )

Comment: @didierseverac I've added some thoughts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70884740/10197418). In principle, I don't think you can specify the type you want before import, because you would also have to specify the conversion from *any type*  to the type you want.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, use [`pd.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

Setup a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'duration': ['43:24:57', '22:12:52', '-', '78:41:33']})
print(df)

# Output
   duration
0  43:24:57
1  22:12:52
2         -
3  78:41:33
```

```
df['duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['duration'], errors='coerce')
print(df)

# Output
         duration
0 1 days 19:24:57
1 0 days 22:12:52
2             NaT
3 3 days 06:41:33
```

**Update**

> @MrFuppes Excel file is exactly what I have in my column 'duration'

Try:

```
df['duration'] = np.where(df['duration'].apply(len) == 8,
                          '1899-12-31 ' + df['duration'], df['duration'])
df['duration'] = pd.to_datetime(df['duration'], errors='coerce') \
                     - pd.Timestamp('1899-12-31')
print(df)

# Output (with a slightly modified example of @MrFuppes)
         duration
0 0 days 12:30:00
1 1 days 00:30:00
2             NaT
```

Comment: Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Although the Excel input file looks like this, I do not have homogeneous data in that column (in fact your input is what I would like to have)  
I have a mix of properly formated hours (below 24:00) and dates (for those where the time is greater than 24:00
If try :
`code`
df['duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['duration'], errors='coerce')

on my df, I get this :
#Output
 duration
0      NaT
1      NaT
2      NaT
3      NaT
4      NaT
5      NaT
6      NaT
7      NaT
8      NaT
9      NaT
`code`

Comment: Pandas does not interpret data, it reads data as in your file (which is probably not what you see to Excel). Please export your data to a csv file and upload a sample from the content of the csv.

Comment: MrFuppes Excel file is exactly what I have in my column 'duration'

Comment: @didierseverac. I updated my answer, can you check it please?

Comment: @Corralien, It works for the dates but for the times alone it gives me "TypeError: object of type 'NaTType' has no len()"
But I think that you are right, filtering by length could be the answer