# Python Pandas read_excel without converting int to float

Tags: python, pandas

im reading an Excel file:

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\test.xlsx', 'Sheet0', skiprows = 1)
```

The Excel file contains a column formatted General and a value like "405788", after reading this with pandas the output looks like "405788.0" so its converted as float. I need any value as String without changing the values, can someone help me out with this?

[Edit]

If i copy the values in a new Excel file and load this, the integers does not get converted to float. But i need to get the Values correct of the original file, so is there anything i can do?

Options dtype and converted changes the type as i need in str but as a floating number with .0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python pandas: how to specify data types when reading an Excel file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32591466/python-pandas-how-to-specify-data-types-when-reading-an-excel-file)

Comment: Sadly does not work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the dtype attribute of the read_excel method.

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\test.xlsx', 'Sheet0', skiprows = 1,
dtype={'Name': str, 'Value': str})
```

More information in the pandas docs:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: Its get converted to String like i need, but before its get converted to an float so that it shows the number with .0

Comment: Hm okay, weird. I tried it again and for me it works. I get back the exact same number with this approach but as a string without any .0 at the end.

Comment: It must be any strange formatting in the Excel file i need to use, if i copy the values and paste them into a new Book, it works fine.