# Apply function to two columns of a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm finding several answers to this question, but none that seem to address or solve the error that pops up when I apply them. Per e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331698/how-to-apply-a-function-to-two-columns-of-pandas-dataframe) I have a dataframe `df` and a function `my_func(string_1,string_2)` and I'm attempting to create a new column with the following:

```
df.['new_column'] = df.apply(lambda x: my_func(x['old_col_1'],x['old_col_2']),axis=1)
```

I'm getting an error originating inside `my_func` telling me that `old_col_1` is type float and not a string as expected.  In particular, the first line of `my_func` is `old_col_1 = old_col_1.lower()`, and the error is

> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'lower'

By including debug statements using dataframe printouts I've verified `old_col_1` and `old_col_2` are indeed both strings.  If I explicitly cast them to strings when passing as arguments, then `my_func` behaves as you would expect if it were being fed numeric data cast as strings, though the column values are decidedly not numeric.

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32591466/python-pandas-how-to-specify-data-types-when-reading-an-excel-file) I've even explicitly ensured these columns are not being "intelligently" cast incorrectly when creating the dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheetname,header=0,converters={'old_col_1':str,'old_col_2':str})
```

The function `my_func` works very well when it's called on its own.  All this is making me suspect that the indices or some other numeric data from the dataframe is being passed, and not (exclusively) the column values.

Other implementations seem to give the same problem.  For instance,

```
df['new_column'] = np.vectorize(my_func)(df['old_col_1'],df['old_col_2'])
```

produces the same error.  Variations (e.g. using `df['old_col_1'].to_numpy()` or `df['old_col_1'].values` in place of `df['old_col_1']`) don't change this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that you have a np.nan/None/null data in your columns? If so you might be getting an error similar to the one that is caused with this data

```
data = {
    'Column1' : ['1', '2', np.nan, '3']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Column1'] = df['Column1'].apply(lambda x : x.lower())
df
```

Comment: Thanks! This prompted me to look back at the output of explicitly casting to string (i.e. `df.apply(lambda x: my_func(str(x['old_col_1']),str(x['old_col_2'])),axis=1)`, and on closer examination the function is working as intended.  So I think you're right, and I'm working now to put some exception handling into the function.