# Some columns in pandas dataframe appear as NaN when they aren't blank

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a pretty large dataframe. Most of the columns are being read just fine but there's a specific column called 'Delivered?' where each cell is either going to have the text "Yes", "No", or "Partially". But when I print that column every item shows as NaN.

Here's the code I have now:
`file = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name="April") print(file['Delivered?'])`

I've tried change the 'dtype' and adding 'converters' and changing the column from a general type to a text type but nothing worked. When I run the above code this is what I get:

```
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
6    NaN
7    NaN
8    NaN
9    NaN
10   NaN
.
.
.


Name: Delivered?, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Do other columns return the correct values?

Comment: 'Name: Delivered?, dtype: float64' is your problem you need to set up the reader to specifically look for a type that matches the column.  You are looking for numbers, not a string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32591466/python-pandas-how-to-specify-data-types-when-reading-an-excel-file will answer your problems

Comment: @PaulBrennan I've tried converting to str but now it says the dtype is 'object' but still returns NaN. if I use type(<item>) it says <class 'float'>. Do I just need to implement some kind of __str__ method?