# Python pandas date formating changing to 1970 while running script in linux

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to run a Python script to convert the date format of the CSV column to yyyy-dd-mm format but the date is changing to 1970. here is the script I am running My date looks like 20230915124356. This script ran for few times correctly producing 2023-09-15 but it's working afterwards I am running from Linux shell

```
import python as pandas
df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv')


df['Form Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Form Date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')


df.to_csv('your_file.csv', index=False)
```

tried running from linux terminal bt values are showing as 1970

Comment: Be explicit, provide a clear reproducible example of the CSV file which reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Good question.  This happens because pandas reads your datetime value within the csv as an integer but it expects a string.  Try this after loading your csv

```
In [18]: df.dtypes
Out[18]: 
Form Date     int64
```

See, an integer.

You need the date to be a string.  There are a couple options here.  You can change the dtype after loading your csv via:

```
df["Form Date"] = df["Form Date"].asdtype(str)
```

Alternatively, you can specify the dtype when loading the csv [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32591786/1678467):

```
df = pd.read_csv("your_file.csv", converters={'Form Date':str})
```

Either way, you can now convert to datetime using your original code.