# Converting Excel to CSV python

Tags: python

I am using xlrd to convert my .xls Excel file to a CSVfile yet when I try to open the workbook my program crashes sending an error message

```
bof_error('Expected BOF record; found %r' % self.mem[savpos:savpos+8])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlrd/book.py", line 1224, in bof_error
    raise XLRDError('Unsupported format, or corrupt file: ' + msg)
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found 'Chrom\tPo'
```

The `Chrom\tPo` is part of my header for the excel file yet I don't understand what the error is with the Excel file and how to change it.

The program crashes right when i try to open the excel file using xlrd.open_workbook('Excel File')

Comment: What version of xlrd are you using, and what type of Excel file (xls vs xlsx)?

Comment: Is the error while converting the file, or after it's converted when you try to open it?

Comment: Dan - The version of xlrd i am using is 1.0.0 and i am using .xls.  And the error occurs when converting the file when I try to xlrd.open_workbook(excelfile)

Answer (score 1):

I would use `openpyxl` for this.

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_name)
ws = wb.worksheets[page_number]
table = []
for row_num in range(ws.get_highest_row()):
  temp_row = []
  for col_num in range(ws.get_highest_column()):
    temp_row.append(ws.cell(row=row_num, col=col_num).value)
  table.append(temp_row[:])
```

This will give you the contents of the sheet as a 2-D list, which you can then write out to a csv or use as you wish.

If you're stuck with `xlrd` for whatever reason, You may just need to convert your file from `xls` to `xlsx`

Comment: I realized that the error was that even though the file was saved with the name .xls it was actually a tab delimited file and  I needed to save it as a xls file and then everything worked.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer from a previous question: [How to save an Excel worksheet as CSV from Python (Unix)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802417/how-to-save-an-excel-worksheet-as-csv-from-python-unix)

The answer goes for openpyxl and xlrd.