# Concatenate two folder names

Tags: python, concatenation, directory

This should be easy enough, but I'm stuck on it for too much.

How do I concatenate two folder names?

For example:

```
ws = r'C:\Temp' 
folder = "Test"
```

I want to get a result of `c:\Temp\Test` but everything I do results in `c:\TempTest`.

I can't use `+ "\"` because it's invalid operation.

Comment: You can't use "/" ? "C:/Temp/Test" should also do

Comment: You should definitely use @Tichodroma's answer. This will handle path concatenation correctly and platform-independently for you in all circumstances. The reason why `"\"` (or even `r"\"`) didn't work is that the backslash is an escape character. Even in a raw string, the backslash is an escape character for the single use case of escaping the quote character. Therefore, you can't have a string that ends in a single backslash.

Answer (score 13):

Use [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html?highlight=path#os.path.join) for this.

```
os.path.join(r'C:\Temp', 'Test')
```

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2422864/383793) the '\' should be a '/'... I have no windows to double check.