# Python error: "cannot find path specified"

Tags: python, text, random, path

```
import os
import random

os.chdir("C:\Users\Mainuser\Desktop\Lab6")

#Am i supposed to have a os.chdir? 
# I think this is what's giving the error
#how do i fix this? 

def getDictionary():
      result = []
      f = open("pocket-dic.txt","r")
      for line in f:
            result = result + [ line.strip() ];
      return result

def makeText(dict, words=50):
      length = len(dict)
      for i in range(words):
            num = random.randrange(0,length)
            words = dict[num]
            print word,
            if (i+1) % 7 == 0:
                  print
```

Python gives me an error saying it cannot find the path specified, when i clearly have a folder on my desktop with that name. It might be the os.chidr?? what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Always use raw strings: `r"C:\Users\Mainuser\Desktop\Lab6"`

Comment: Learn about relative addressing. This will allow the file to be somewhere besides `C:\Users\Mainuser\Desktop\`

Comment: @hcwhsa : a little explanation on this rather blunt comment ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Backslash is a special character in Python strings, as it is in many other languages. There are lots of alternatives to fix this, starting with doubling the backslash:

```
"C:\\Users\\Mainuser\\Desktop\\Lab6"
```

using a raw string:

```
r"C:\Users\Mainuser\Desktop\Lab6"
```

or using `os.path.join` to construct your path instead:

```
os.path.join("c:", os.sep, "Users", "Mainuser", "Desktop", "Lab6")
```

`os.path.join` is the safest and most portable choice. As long as you have "c:" hardcoded in the path it's not really portable, but it's still the best practice and a good habit to develop.

With a tip of the hat to [Python os.path.join on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422798/python-os-path-join-on-windows) for the correct way to produce c:\Users rather than c:Users.

Comment: +1 for actual proper way of doing so. (path.join rather than escaping \).

Comment: in my specific use case "./path/to/folder" format worked

Comment: This still does not solve the problem, because OP wants to find the folder on the Desktop, but changed the current working directory into a folder on the Desktop.

Answer (score 3):

Backslashes have special meaning inside Python strings. You either need to double them up or use a [raw string](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals): `r"C:\Users\Mainuser\Desktop\Lab6"` (note the `r` before the opening quote).