# Edit path name in windows - generalized

Tags: python

I have a python script running in windows that detects the user profile using `os.environ['UserProfile']`.  I need to amend this path in order to perform some operations.

For example. I read in:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop
```

and need to create:

```
C':\'Users'\'User'\'Desktop
```

basically surrounding all non-letters and non-numbers with single quotes.

I'm wondering if there's a best, most general way to do this.  `re`?  `split`?  `os.join`?  Ideally, I want to do it with full generality, independent of path name or os.

Here's my current clunky code to achieve it:

```
for letter in amend_dir:
    if amend_dir[track] not in string.ascii_letters:
        if amend_dir[track-1] in string.ascii_letters:
            if amend_dir[track+1] not in string.ascii_letters:
                newer_letter = "'"+letter
    if amend_dir[track] not in string.ascii_letters:
        if amend_dir[track-1] not in string.ascii_letters:
            if amend_dir[track+1] in string.ascii_letters:
                newer_letter = letter+"'"
    if amend_dir[track] not in string.ascii_letters:
        if amend_dir[track-1] in string.ascii_letters:
            if amend_dir[track+1] in string.ascii_letters:
                    newer_letter = "'"+letter+"'"
```

EDIT:

I didn't have much luck with the os module, but this 2-liner works nicely:

amend_dir = (parameters['default_dir'].replace('\',"'\'"))
amend2_dir = (amend_dir.replace(":'\'", "':\'"))

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422798/python-os-path-join-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

There are already generalised pathname manipulation tools aplenty in the standard module `os.path` just use that.

Remember that windows is unusual in the use of `\` and `L:` notations the os.path modules handle this cleanly for you.

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this:

```
import re
x = r'C:\Users\User\Desktop'
re.sub(r'([^\w]+)',"'\g<1>'",x)
```