# open excel file python so it is visible

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm trying to open a excel so it is displayed visibly.

I am using:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(['open', '-a', 'C:\\1\\2\\22.xlsx'])
```

https://ibb.co/eOhY4b

Sorry if this is obvious but I keep getting this error message.  AS far as I can tell the file is located there.

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: try `import os` and use `os.path.join('C:', '1', '2', '22.xlsx')` as your path argument, instead of formatting in manually.

Comment: @jo9k Strange, I'm on windows 10 and this does nothing for me. I did find work around though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it didn't work just because `open` isn't a known command name (this is an action in the windows registry, nothing more). The `subprocess` error message:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

has only *one* meaning: the executable could not be found. It doesn't (and cannot) check the parameters to see if they're valid filepaths so don't look in that direction (and yes, it's a pity that the message is generic and doesn't say exactly which file could not be found, that a known windows issue)

That would work:

```
import os
os.startfile(r'C:\1\2\22.xlsx')
```

[os.startfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.startfile) tries to perform the same thing as when you're clicking on the file in windows explorer.

This solution has the advantage not to depend on `win32com`.

Aside/discussed in comments: `os.path.join('C:', '1', '2', '22.xlsx')` doesn't work because it doesn't add the backslash after the drive colon (and for a "good" reason (well a good reason windows-wise): [Python os.path.join on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422798/python-os-path-join-on-windows/2422847#2422847)).

```
>>> os.path.join('C:', '1', '2', '22.xlsx')
'C:1\\2\\22.xlsx'  # wrong
```

a clean way to do it:

```
>>> os.path.join('C:', os.sep,'1' , '2', '22.xlsx')
'C:\\1\\2\\22.xlsx'
```

Comment: I think this should be ```īmport os```, not ```īmport subprocess```?

Comment: you're completely right. fixed

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why

```
import os
os.path.join('C:', '1', '2', '22.xlsx')
```

Did not work.  I think it worked but there was no visible excel.

Anyway, this works

```
xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True

xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\\1\\2\\22.xlsx")
```