# os.path.join() on windows?

Tags: python, path

I would like to write this code on windows :
os.path.join(folder1 + "/" + folder2)

it works fine in MAC but in windows it gives me an error:  OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\Users\Khalaf\Desktop\test\dataset-images\x.jpg' -> 'C:\Users\Khalaf\Desktop\test\dataset-images\C:\Users\Khalaf\Desktop\test\dataset-images-1.jpg'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python os.path.join on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422798/python-os-path-join-on-windows)

Comment: You have to use `os.path.join()` properly: `os.path.join(folder1, folder2)`. The divider is added by the function.

Comment: I need the "/" between paths

Comment: You can use `os.pathsep` instead of `/` as well.

Comment: On Windows you do *not* "need / between paths" because / is an illegal character in a Windows filename. `os.path.join()`  knows that, even if you don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
os.path.join(folder1 + "\\" + folder2)
```

MAC and Linux work with singe /

but in Windows we have to pass \\

Try these it will work

Comment: i did, it gives me :

OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\Users\\Khalaf\\Desktop\\test\\dataset-images\\x.jpg' -> 'C:\\Users\\Khalaf\\Desktop\\test\\dataset-images\\C:\\Users\\Khalaf\\Desktop\\test\\dataset-images-1.jpg'

Comment: Please share folder1 and folder2 path

Comment: i solved it using : os.path.basename, thank you very much for your tips

Answer (score 0):

seperate the two folders with commas

```
os.path.join(folder1, folder2)
```

The function creates the equivalent for windows which i think is \

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to learn python and am making a program that will output a script. I want to use os.path.join, but am pretty confused.

os.path.join('c:', 'sourcedir')

when I use the copytree command, Python will output it the desired way, for example:

import shutil

src = os.path.join('c:', 'src')

dst = os.path.join('c:', 'dst')

shutil.copytree(src, dst)

Windows has a concept of current directory for each drive. Because of that, "c:sourcedir" means "sourcedir" inside the current C: directory, and you'll need to specify an absolute directory.

Any of these should work and give the same result, but I don't have a Windows VM fired up at the moment to double check:

"c:/sourcedir"

os.path.join("/", "c:", "sourcedir")

os.path.join("c:/", "sourcedir")

Answer (score 0):

Tried below on windows:

```py
user= os.getlogin()
os.path.join("C:\\Users",user,"TestAutomationDownloads")
```

Result - A directory got created in windows at path `c:Users\USERNAME\TestAutomationDownloads`
where username gets its value from variable `user =os.getlogin()`
`os.path.join` adds "\" itself before and after variable.