# How do I correctly use the os.path to locate a file stored in a specific folder?

Tags: python, json, debugging, os.path

I'm new to python and I've not used os.path that often, but as my projects grew and I started trying to integrate multiple folders together, I realized that it is probably best that I start using the os.path method.

I'm currently trying to get to a json file `data.json` in a folder (that is within several other folders). I looked at the way it is done online but I think I confused myself.

```py
import os 
import json

x = os.path.join('c:', 'data.json')
data = json.loads(open(x).read())
print(data)
```

Error message:
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Obada\\OneDrive\\Documents\\VS Code Projects\\Basic Chatbot\\data'`

Comment: I found a way to use the raw string method, but I still feel like the os.path method might be better, not sure though.

Comment: Can you post your "solution"?

Comment: @ScottHunter The raw string method is just using `r"fullPath"`, just an r before the string and `fullPath` just being the entire path to that file. For example mine turned out as such: `r"C:\Users\Obada\OneDrive\Documents\VS Code Projects\Basic Chatbot\intents.json"`

. I didn't post it as a solution because it's different from the os.path method, which I'm still curious about

Comment: the error message doesn't seem to match the code above, where does that long path come from?  if you `print(x)` does it look like a valid path?

Comment: @Anentropic I just realized that it does not, this is the full path to the .json file `C:\Users\Obada\OneDrive\Documents\VS Code Projects\Basic Chatbot\data.json`, I think I had mixed up one of my attempts with this one, but I can see why the file couldn't be located on "`c:data.json`". I'm not sure how I can do it properly, do I add the inbetween for the path alongside the drive ( `('c:','\Users\Obada\OneDrive\Documents\VS Code Projects\Basic Chatbot\', 'data.json'`  ) or do I have to add it in as another string between the drive and file?

Comment: It's a long time since I used Windows, but it seems there's a couple of things happening: 1) `c:data.json` is understood as a relative path on the specified drive (weird!) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats#traditional-dos-paths and 2) for some reason Python os.path.join does not add separator when first segment is a drive letter, see further info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422798/python-os-path-join-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using **os.listdir()** method for seeing the existing files in the currently active folder (you can use **os.getcwd()**) to see that.

```
import os 
import json

files = os.listdir()
x = os.path.join('c:', 'data.json')
for i in files:
    if x in files:
        data = json.loads(open(x).read())
        print(data)
    else:
        print("File doesn't exist!")
```

There are better ways to do this, but I am trying to keep it beginner-friendly as you are new to python.

Comment: `dir` is a bad variable name in Python as there is a built-in function `dir`

Comment: Oops! My bad. I will edit it out

Answer (score 0):

The `path.join()` function is for programs that you want to run in diferent os, in this example you dont have to use the join function.

The join function just join the 2 strings with a `/` or `\` depending on the os

In this example its windows so it use `\`

If its in the c partition you can just use the full (raw) address.

But if the address is relative like this example:

```
.\example.json
```

Its depend on the current file or folder that you are in, in this case the python script, you should use the join function

Answer (score 0):

if you are on Windows, you can reach a file in C:\ by using something like this. Note that the second slash is because we need to tell python that it is a \

```
import os
fullfilename = os.path.join('C:\\', 'data.json')
data = json.loads(open(fullfilename).read())
print(data)
```

Another useful option is getcwd, which will give you the current directory python is running on.

```
currdir = os.getcwd()
FILEPATH = os.path.join(currdir,"data.json")
```

This will ensure that everything is working relative to the directory you are running your code from... no matter where you move the code